# Javascript and 3d games

Tags: javascript, cordova, 3d-engine

I was just wondering. Is there a game engine available for creating 3d games? because I am planning to create a PhoneGap game so that it is playable inside a magazine app that I am creating and of course, take advantage of PhoneGap's fast deployment on several devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is NOT the way to go for this. Use flash if you can.

Though, I did stumble across: http://raphaeljs.com/scape/

Welcome to svg hell.